# Mantel's Theorem proof verification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I found the following proof for Mantel's theorem in Lecture 1 of [David Conlon's "Extremal graph theory" course](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/Extremal-course.html). I cannot understand the equality that I have highlighted in the image was arrived at. I would appreciate some assistance.

> **Theorem 1 (Mantel's theorem)** *If a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices contains no triangle then it contains at most $\frac {n^2}{4}$ edges.
>
> **First proof** Suppose that $G$ has $m$ edges. Let $x$ and $y$ be two vertices in $G$ which are joined by an edge. If $d(v)$ is the degree of a vertex $v$, we see that $d(x)+d(y)\leq n$. This is because every vertex in the graph $G$ is connected to at most one of $x$ and $y$. Note now that 
>   $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{
>    \sum_x d^2(x)=\sum_{x,y\in E} \big( d(x)+d(y)\big)
>    }
>    \leq mn.$$
>   On the other hand, since $\sum_x d(x)=2m$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that 
>   $$\sum_x d^2(x)\geq\frac{\big(\sum_x d(x)\big)^2}{n} \geq \frac{4m^2}{n}.$$
>   Therfore
>   $$\frac{4m^2}{n} \leq mn,$$
>   and the result follows. $\tag*{$\square$}$

For people with visulal limitations, the highlighted part is: $$\sum_x d^2(x)=\sum_{x,y\in E} \big( d(x)+d(y)\big) \leq mn.$$

Comment: Sorry, How did you apply Cauchy schwarz inequality?

Comment: @mathpadawan Label the vertices $v_1,...,v_n$. Use the vectors $v = (deg(v_1), deg(v_2),...,deg(v_n))$ and $w = (1,1,...,1)$ with $n$ ones in Cauchy-Schwarz and that inequality falls out.

Comment: I think this is more like inequality between quadratic and linear means.

Answer (score 13):

Pick any vertex $x \in V$ of degree $k$ (that is, let $k = d(x)$). Then $G$ contains $k$ edges of the form:
$$
xy_1, xy_2, \ldots, xy_k
$$
where $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_k \in V$. Hence, in the summation:
$$
\sum_{xy \in E}(d(x) + d(y))
$$
we know that the term $d(x)$ will appear exactly $k$ times. In other words, the vertex $x$ will contribute an amount of:
$$
\underbrace{d(x) + d(x) + \cdots + d(x)}_{k \text{ times}} = k \cdot d(x) = d(x) \cdot d(x) = d^2(x)
$$
Thus, since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that:
$$
\sum_{xy \in E}(d(x) + d(y)) = \sum_{x \in V} d^2(x)
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 6):

In the sum $S:=\sum_{xy\in E}\bigl(d(x)+d(y)\bigr)$ the ends $x$ and $y$ of each edge $e=xy$  get  $d(x)$, resp. $d(y)$,  points each. This means that every vertex $x\in V$ gets $d(x)$ points for each edge having an end at $x$. It follows that $S=\sum_{x\in V}d^2(x)$.