# Pigeonhole to bound the number of pairs of points that are a given distance apart

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

The problem: Suppose we have some set $X$ of $n$ points in the circle centered at the origin with radius $\frac{1}{2}$. Show that the number of pairs of points $x_{1}, x_{2}$ in $X$ whose distance $|x_{1} - x_{2}|$ apart is greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is at most $\lfloor \frac{n^{2}}{3} \rfloor.$ Show this is sharp for $n \geq 2$.

So far, I've tried to place a grid on a square over the points in the circle to apply the pigeonhole principle as one usually does for these sorts of problems, but I can't arrive at the actual conclusion. How can one prove this?

Comment: What is $n$...?

Comment: @HappyDay |X|; has been updated

Comment: Are you using "strictly greater than"? For "distance $ \geq 1/\sqrt{2}$", for $n = 4$, we can get 6 pairs by using a square, while $ \lfloor 4^2/4 \rfloor = 5$.

Comment: @CalvinLin But the pairs of points across the diagonal of that square will be $1/2 + 1/2 = 1$ unit of distance apart, since the radius of the circle is $1/2$, no?

Comment: @greentnt Yes, and $1$ is $\ge 1/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that there is **no quadrilateral** in the circle defined in your problem whose **sides** and **diagonals** are all greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ because, as shown below, if all sides are greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, then at least one diagonal is greater than $1$ (to prove this use the law of cosines and the fact that, at least one angle of the quadrilateral is greater than or equal to $\ 90^{\circ}$).
[image]

---

Now, assume $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are the points in the circle. Let's assume that $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are vertices of a graph. If the distance $|x_i-x_j|$ is  greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, then add the edge connecting $x_i$ and $x_j$. Based on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858559/prove-that-a-graph-on-n-vertices-which-not-contains-k-4-as-a-subgraph-has-at), if the constructed graph has $[\frac{n^2}{3}]+1$ edges, then it has a subgraph of $K_4$, which contradicts the fact that there is **no quadrilateral** in the circle defined in your problem whose sides and diagonal are all greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.

---

For the last part of the problem, for example if $n=3k+1$, put $k+1$ points inside the circle $C_1$, $k$ points inside circles $C_2$ and $C_3$. It is very easy to see that we can have circles $C_1, C_2$, and $C_3$ such that every point in each of the three circles is at a distance of greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ from every point of the two other circles. Then,

$$[\frac{n^2}{3}]=3k^2+2k=k(k+1)+k(k+1)=k^2.$$

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the help.