# What's the smallest cycle that a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges must have?

Tags: graph-theory

What's the highest number of edges that a simple undirected graph with $n$ vertices can have, without having any cycle smaller than $k$?

I'm looking for the case where $n$ is "unbounded", or "$\lim n\rightarrow \infty$", i.e. where $n$ is "large enough". The given $k$ may be a function in $n$.

---

The inverted case is that I'm looking for the behavior of $f_n(m)$. Informally, we're looking to construct a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges while avoiding small cycles. $f_n(m)$ is then the size of the smallest cycle in the optimal case:

Of all simple graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, select the one where its smallest cycle is as large as possible. $f_n(m)$ is then the size of that cycle. Note that $f_n$ should be a monotonically decreasing function.

Yet another way to look at it: all graphs with n vertices and m edges have a cycle of size $k=f_n(m)$ or smaller.

For $k=4$, I think the answer is $n^2/4$: the complete bipartite graph with $n/2$ vertices on both sides. But I don't have a final proof that more than $n^2/4$ is impossible.

So I think we have (for $n$ even):

- $f_n(n^2/4) = 4$
- $f_n(n^2/4+1) = 3$ (edit: definitely, see saulspatz's comment)

Some trivial cases:

- $f_n(n) = n$ ([If a graph with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges there must a cycle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414733/if-a-graph-with-n-vertices-and-n-edges-there-must-a-cycle))
- $f_n(m_{<n}) = \infty$ or undefined (There exist graphs with less edges than vertices that have no cycles)
- $f_n(n(n-1)/2) = 3$. (complete simple graphs have all cycles and cycles in simple graphs in general have a minimum length of 3).

Upper-bounds for $f_n(m)$ in terms of $m$ (and $n$) might be useful for my application, but asymptotic bounds (big-O notation) aren't good enough. Such an upper bound simply guarantees that my graph with $m$ edges has a cycle of a certain small-enough size.

Comment: A graph with more than $\frac{n^2}4$ edges contains a $3$-cycle by [Mantel's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628877/mantels-theorem-proof-verification)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a classical Turan-type problem. You are looking for the extremal parameter :
$$ ex(n,\{C_3,C_4,\ldots,C_k\})$$
i.e. the maximum number of edges in a graph of order $n$ and girth at least $g \geq k+1$ (the smallest cycle has length at least $k+1$).

You should have a look at [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07004751) by Tang, Lin, Balbuena and Miller, and other related articles  : google scholar [list](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?cites=9323780624219284935&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en), or [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X10001010) showing explicit constructions.

For instance it follows from a work of Lazebnik and Wang that

> for  $n\geq12$,  $ex(2n+2,\{C_3,C_4,\ldots,C_n\})=2n+4$, and there exists an extremal graph  G  with girth $n+2$. (meaning that trying to have the maximum number of edge in a graph or order $2n+2$, while avoiding all cycles of length up to $n$, forces you to avoid cycles of length $n+1$)

Also, [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X10002659) by Abajo and Dianez give a good overview of results for small $k$